# Which process to connect to when debugging webapi in a azure service

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

Does anyone know which service to connect to when debugging webapi deployed in a azure service?

Comment: Is it deployed to a cloud service or mobile services?

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged your question on 'azure-web-roles' I assumed you deployed your WebAPI in a web role. So you'd connect to w3wp.exe when debugging since it's running under IIS.